# WCF C# Windows Store APP I am getting this exception “There was no endpoint listening at [URL] that could accept the message…”

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-store-apps, wcf-endpoint

I made a WCF that connects SQL DB and get data to a Windows Store App... Yesterday worked just fine. I could get the data from the DB to the Client app. Today I open the solution again and for my surprise it just stop working just like that...

I 've been searching in foruns some ideias but didn't get any positive result.

I didn't change a single line of code, and I really don't know what is happening. I tried to make a new solution, a new project with that funcionality and nothing, just doesn't work.
I tried to change the wcf app.config but without any success.
Can someone please give me some ideias to solve it???

this is the my WCF app.congif file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="WcfBD.Properties.Settings.ProjetoFinalConnectionString"
  connectionString="Data Source=Asus;Initial Catalog=ProjetoFinal;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service name="WcfBD.BaseDadosWCF">
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfBD.IBaseDadosWCF">
 <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfBD/Service1/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
 <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
 </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: check your project web.config file endpoint address is same as you have mentioned in app.config

Comment: @DhavalPatel my client referece.scvmap file have this endpoint address:
` <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfBD/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sharing my WCF service configuration for your reference. you check your service contract

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"/>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="DataService.DataService">
    <endpoint address="web" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="DataService.IDataService"/>
     <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding" contract="DataService.IDataService"  />
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="DataService.IDataService"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"  faultExceptionEnabled="True" defaultBodyStyle="Bare" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="True"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" allowCookies="true">
      <security mode="None"></security>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
 <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding" allowCookies="true">
      <security mode="None"></security>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your webserver is not working fine ? I assume that if you didn't touch anything, it could be a webserver problem. First, take a look at your IIS and may be try to restart it.

Comment: I think webserver is not the problem because I'm able to consume others WCF.. That one, was the only one that stopped to work :(

Comment: It's may be a weird question but did you try a ping to your endpoint ? localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfBD/Service1 , if you didn't change any line of code from you web service, focus yourself on the environment that could have change ? Network ? Client ? Firewall ? Security ? Port ?...

Comment: In this moment I accept any question =)... I'm without ideias.. The WCF is in the same solution of the client app... Same solution but different projects. I'm working locally, I even disable my anti-virus to try it...

Comment: Try to call your web service with SOAPUI to make sure that is not a client call or configuration problem. And beside SOAPUI is such a nice application to test your WCF webservice :)

Comment: You're welcome, could you also try to add "http://" to your adress in your client base adresse ? You could also check if the contract ".wsdl" is available from your IE or firefox browser

Comment: I think you are right I can´t reach the WCF from the browser. But how can I solve it now???

Comment: Try to restart your iis pool or virtual directory wherein your wcf is located, just in case :)

Comment: Problem solved with system restore... not the best way but, solved my problem... for now... lol